# Rewriting an anomymous function for Action using Lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am not able to figure out how this can be simplified using the Lambda expressions:

```
this.Server.IterateItems(delegate (Item i)
                            {
                                if (i.Name=="TEST")
                                {
                                    i.Destroy();
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: what expects IterateItems(...) to get ?

Comment: In general just replace `delegate (…) {…}` with `… => {…}` so `(Item i) => {…}`. The type can usually be inferred automatically, so this can be simplified to `(i) => {…}`. As the brackets around a single argument can also be omitted your delegate can finally be reduced to `i => {…}`.

Comment: Is there a `Server.Items` property? Where does `IterateItems` get items from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
this.Server.IterateItems((i) => 
                            {
                                if (i.Name=="TEST")
                                {
                                    i.Destroy();
                                }
                            });
```